# Nested PFQuery's in HandleWatchKitExtensionRequest

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, watchkit

I'm trying to nest 2 PFQuery's inside HandleWatchKitExtensionRequest so that I can get the data passed back to my Watch Extension in my reply.  In the code below the first Query (for a PFUser matching the given userName) returns, but I cannot get the second (for a list of the User's people) to return.  Is there some limitation I'm missing on making multiple queries within the same block?  Is my background task timing out before this long running request can return?

*I edited my code so that nameList is not an optional, but still no return value.   While the same block (nested findObjectsInBackGroundBlocks) executes and returns perfectly in my IOS app.

Extending the time of the delay of background task didn't help.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {


    var dictionary = userInfo! as NSDictionary


    if let currentUserName: AnyObject = dictionary.objectForKey("currentUserName") {
        if let currentUserNameAsString = currentUserName as? String {


            // Bogus task for keeping app going
            var bogusTask = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler { () -> Void in
            }
            // End bogus task after 2 seconds
            delay(2.0, closure: { () -> () in
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(bogusTask)
            })

            // look up current user logged in on phone from name passed from Watch
            let query = PFUser.query()
            query!.whereKey("username", equalTo: currentUserNameAsString)
            query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in

                if let user = objects?.first as? PFUser {

                    var testName: String?
                    var nameList:  String = []
                    let query = PFQuery(className: Person.parseClassName())
                    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: user)

                    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
                        if let people = objects as? [Person] {
                            for person in people {
                                if let name = person.name {
                                nameList.append(name)
                                    testName = nameList.first
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        testName = ("test")
                    }






                let testDict = ["success" : testName!]
                reply(testDict)

                 UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(bogusTask) // End the bogusTask in case the work was faster than 2 seconds
                    }
                }


                }

            }




}

// Utility function for delay
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        closure
    )
}
```

Comment: Why are you ending your background task in two different places? You end it in the closure where you begin the background task, and nothing else is in that closure, so that piece of code effectively does nothing.

Comment: Thanks I updated my question with a better background task solution, but still have the same issue that I can return the first Query but not the second?

Comment: What are you expecting it to return, and what is the actual result?

Comment: I know the Queries are correct since they're the same in my IOS app...the second query should return an array of people...but in my test code I'm just testing whether the 2nd findobjects is executing and it is not.

Comment: Have you tried it without the background task to see if it will get executed?

Comment: Yes, the background task was attempt to get this second query to work, I can return from the first frindobjects  without the background task, but again not the second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are calling "reply(testDict)" outside of your nested query.

Since the query is asynchronous the "reply(testDict)" is probably being called before the nested query is finished executing.

Comment: So simple, but you're absolutely right!!  duh...  Thanks PJ!